# could not load file or assembly system.data.sqlite on target machine

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've a windows form, connected to a sqlite db.
The application is running fine on my pc, but when I run it on any other pc I get the Message:

```
    could not load file or assembly 'system.data.sqlite, version=1.0.84.0. culture=neutral, publickey token=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of irs dependencies
```

I've tried to change App.xml to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```

The target machine has .NET 4.5 installed, and the problem isn't about .NET because the message only appears on classes that use sqlite.
I've tried to install Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable x86 but that didn't solve the problem.
But when I Installed Visual Studio, it worked like charm.
How should I run my application without installing Visual Studio on client machine?

Comment: The file is present I assume?

Comment: the reference for sqlite is set to "copy to local"

Comment: Yes, but on that other computer, you remembered to copy all the files, including that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQLite .NET assemblies are not part of the .NET Framework or Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable x86; you should deploy them with your application.

From the [System.Data.SQLite FAQ](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki):

> The recommended way to deploy the assemblies is "application local"
>   (i.e. copy them to the directory the application is installed to)

Also don't forget the native interop DLLs; you basically need to deploy like this:

```
- YourApp.exe
- System.Data.SQLite.dll
- x86/SQLite.Interop.dll
- x64/SQLite.Interop.dll
```

Comment: the reference for sqlite is set to "copy to local"

Comment: @user3379482 but are you copying them to the _target_ PC alongside your app?

Comment: I've copied all the contents of "Debug" folder to the target machine..It contains system.data.sqlute.dll too, and it doesn't work till I install Visual studio

Comment: where should I get interop  dlls??

Comment: @user3379482 the easiest way to get all correct versions in a bundle _and_ make sure everything is configured right for deployment on build, is to install SQLite via Nugget, otherwise, you can find the correct version [here](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Comment: I've installed sqlite-netFx45-setup-bundle-x86-2012-1.0.84.0 and it worked!! thanks Saeb